# Does crashlytics report iOS Freezes (like ANRs in Google)

Tags: crashlytics

I have 4 mobile apps (2 each iOS and Android) written in Xamarin. I am looking for a comprehensive diagnostic tool, and am considering Crashyltics.

Our current coverage lacks reporting on freezes in iOS. Does Crashlytics cover this?

In addition, how much time does it take to install? From my reading you only have to enter some code and you are good. One of my developers tells me that he would have to put code in every try...catch in all the apps.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this time Crashlytics doesn't report OOMs in iOS. The team has considered it but has not found a perfect approach. Thanks.